# inline DIVs inside a container always pushing the last one into second line in WebKit

Tags: html, css, webkit, blink

When trying to hand-made a slider, I noticed that, in Webkit/Blink (Chrome Desktop and Android stock browser), the last slide under my CSS will always be pushed into the next line, no matter how much slides in the container:

```js
// dynamatically insert the "scene"s
// so no white space and/or line breaks occurs
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.container"),function(container){
    var scene;
    // number of children doesn't matter
    var all=Math.floor(Math.random()*15)+1;
    for(var i=0;i<all;i++){
        scene=document.createElement("div");
        scene.className="scene";
        scene.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        container.appendChild(scene);
    }
});
```

```css
div.container
{
    width:50px;
    overflow:visible;
    white-space:pre;
    outline:1px solid red;
}
div.container > div.scene
{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFF, #000);
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:20px;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- prepare the container -->
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

I also made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgzd1L7s/1/)

This is what it looks like in three major browsers:

[image: browser compare]

Why is WebKit/Blink so special in this case, and how can I make them behave like Gecko/Trident?

---

#### Edit:

- The `width:50px` in `.container` is just a convenience way to demonstrate the problem; in real product it's `100%` viewport width, and `width:100%` in `.scene` is actually intended, instead of hard-coded `50px`;
- The `.scene`s in real product are usually images that I may not know their dimension before hand, so the `height:50px` here is just to make the output looks more "clean", and the `height:auto` in `.container` is intended.

Comment: you'll probably need to reset some UA styles..

Comment: @maioman I would love to know which UA styles should I look into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Maybe try `white-space: nowrap;` in `.container` to suppress text wrap and line breaks instead of `white-space: pre;` ( pre preserves new lines). Read more about white-space property here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Note: No clear explanation why this works. Just that Chrome seemed to be wrapping the divs around for some reason. Probably a bug in chrome/webkit.

Comment: Sorry if my initial question didn't make this clear: the `height:50px` is something I may not be able to know beforehand (as they usually are images), and `width:50px` here is just to demonstrate the "overflow" effect, in real life it would be `width:100%`, so I can't hard-code `width:50px` into `.scene`. But thanks for you effort, `float` is a good point.

Comment: Maybe try `white-space: nowrap;` in `.container` to suppress text wrap and line breaks instead of `white-space: pre;` (`pre` preserves new lines).

Read more about `white-space` property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: There's no line breaks here: the `.scene`s are intentionally added by JS so no line breaks and white space between them.

Comment: I tried `white-space:nowrap` to `.container` and the behavior surprisingly "corrected". Can you explain why?

Comment: No, I can't. But I noticed you had the `display` property on the `.scene` divs set to `inline-block` which makes them flow like text and Chrome seemed to be wrapping the divs around for some reason. It's probably just one of those weird browser behaviors. Glad I could help : )

Comment: I think this is a WebKit's bug, so no explanation can be made. Can you update your answer (or post another one) to suggest the `nowrap` trick so I can give you the tick?